# Creating a table for each individual user's timetable data

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

I'm coding an online timetable website which holds all your current subjects you are attending at school and contains slots to write work and it's due date. Mainly for my own personal use, but I guess I could share the URL with a few people when it's completed. Anyway, I have a login / register system set up, linked to a MySQL database. I have the following columns in a table called 'users'.

```
userid, username, firstname, lastname, password
```

Before I attempt anything too stupid, I wanted somebody to give an opinion on what I am about to attempt...

I thought I could write some PHP that creates a table for each new user when they sign up. It would contain all their subjects for each day of the week, and once they input their data it would write it to the database and they wouldn't have to edit their information unless they had to (subject change, etc...)

Would a whole new table for each user's subject data be efficient? The data would have two dimensions: The day of the week (x axis) and the periods of the school day where the subjects are situated (periods 1-6 for my school)

Anyway, thanks for reading, opinions on the best way to go around doing this would be helpful. Thank you.

EDIT: Strawberry's suggestion

```
userid,day,period,subjectid
1      1    1        4
1      1    2        2
1      1    3        5
1      1    4        3
1      1    5        1
1      1    6        7
2      1    1        4
2      1    2        2
2      1    3        5
2      1    4        3
2      1    5        1
2      1    6        7
```

Comment: It's a good thing that you contacted us first

Comment: It'd only make life harder for you if you had one table for each user. Consider the situation where you want to run aggregate reports wherein all users are to be evaluated.

Comment: Right, try to understand what I am saying here, but I need to store two dimensional data for each user. My 'users' table only stores one row for each user, along with their userid, username, firstname, lastname and password. How can I possibly store each day of the week WITH 6 subjects in each day for every single user in one table? @DhruvSaxena

Comment: Haha, thought so. What do you mean, exactly? @Strawberry

Comment: One example of a sensible configuration might be:

    user_id,day,period,subject_id

Comment: And I store the user_id,period,subject_id of every single user in one table? How will I know when the subjects of each user stops and the subjects of the next user starts? @Strawberry

Comment: Because they have a different user_id.

Comment: A few thoughts: you mentioned that `users` table is being used for logins. So, to simplify, you'd start by defining a new table called `subjects`, then a separate table called `user_subjects` which will hold schedules for each subject for every user (and can thereby contain start and end times or dates). Don't be worried about getting all the results in a single query just yet. Keeping the overall structure simple (and by that I mean `normalised`) and manageable should be the priority.

Comment: @Strawberry Check the edit to the question... is that similar to what you were suggesting?

Comment: @DhruvSaxena Why a table for subjects and user_subjects? What is the immediate difference?

Comment: Yes. One intensive day of work each week is more than enough.

Comment: @Caspar The subjects table would have rows for e.g. `English`, `Maths`, `Biology` etc. Just the subject information. The `user_subjects` table is the link between users and subjects - Each user has multiple rows in that `user_subjects` table.

Comment: Subjects by themselves aren't dependent on the existence of any user records - and vice versa - hence the separate entities for `users` and `subjects`. And as indicated above, `user_subjects` shall be the table where the relationship between users and subjects will be defined. Do consider having a read on [normalisation](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php). Incidentally, the link happens to talk about a similar student / subject relationship. :)

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Any problems and I will be sure to ask.

Comment: Cool. But maybe google 'databases 101' or some such first!!

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.